# HTML/CSS - Align horizontaly div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align div horizontally for far too long now.
The thing is, I set the width property but it doesn't seems to do anything.

```css
.vtab
{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 14px 14px;
    width: 100%;
}

.vtab div
{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}

.vtab div.left
{
    width: 25%;
    color:green;
}

.vtab div.middle
{
    width: 50%;
    color:yellow;
}

.vtab div.right
{
    width: 25%;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="vtab">
  <div class="left big">Hello, Jean-Michel</div>
  <div class="middle"><img src="resources/img/banner.png" alt="Company banner" height="75px"/></div>
  <div class="right big"><span class="ti-shopping-cart"> 00.00$</span ></div>
</div>
```

Does anybody have a clue ?
The divs keep stacking on the left of the container div.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Comment: You have a </span> without a <span> and a <span> without a </span>

Comment: Thanks @Gerard !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.vtab
{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 14px 14px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.vtab div
{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.vtab div.left
{
    width: 25%;
    color:green;
}

.vtab div.middle
{
    width: 50%;
    color:yellow;
}

.vtab div.right
{
    width: 25%;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="vtab">
                <div class="left big"><span>Hello, Jean-Michel</span></div>
                <div class="middle"><img src="resources/img/banner.png" alt="Company banner" height="75px"/></div>
                <div class="right big"><span class="ti-shopping-cart"> 00.00$</span></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that using `display:flex;` and `align-items:center;`

```
.vtab {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works as well, not sure wich solution is the best through!